# Finding points of a graph using the given interval

Tags: functions

Given that

$$f(x)= x^3-3x$$ on the interval $[0,2]$

In $(a,b)$ list all of the points of $y=f(x)$ if $a$ is the critical point or endpoint?

Why is the correct answer $-2$ instead of $(1, -2)?$

Comment: I don't really understand what $(a,b)$ is supposed to mean.  You seem to think $b=f(a),$ but I don't see where it says that.  Also, what happened to the endpoints?  Why don't we also have $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)?$

Comment: Here, (a, b) is an open interval meaning that (a, b)={x  R: a< x< b}. So, we don't count x=0 and x=2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for all $x\geq0$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$x^3-3x=x^3+1+1-3x-2\geq3\sqrt[3]{x^3\cdot1^2}-3x-2=-2.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1\in[0,2],$ which says that $-2$ is a minimal value of $f$.

Actually, the minimum point it's $(1,-2)$ and we saw that

it's a point of the global minimum of $f$ on $[0,2]$ because
$$\min_{[0,2]}f=-2.$$

Comment: I inserted my answer (1, -2) but my answer was marked wrong and they showed the answer was only -2. So, that's my problem. -2 doesn't even indicate a point.

Comment: The point on the graph it's $(1,-2).$ Check please a formulation of this problem.